# Sobre implementação de some() e every()

Tags: javascript, funções

Estou tentando entender como funciona a implementação de `some()` e `every()`, porém não entendi muito bem os dois algoritmos de implementação.

- `some()`:

  ```
  Array.prototype.mySome = function(callback, context) {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (callback.call(context, this[i], i, this))
          return true;
  }
  return false;
  };
  ```
- `every()`:

  ```
  Array.prototype.myEvery = function(callback, context) {
   for (var i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
      if (!callback.call(context, this[i], i, this))
          return false;
   }
   return true;
   };
  ```

A minha dúvida é sobre como o `if` de ambas implementações funcionam:

```
if (!callback.call(context, this[i], i, this))
```

Não encontrei nada sobre isso na documentação.
O que esse `if` retorna e por que ele retorna isso?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A forma que ele chama o método `callback` na implementação pode parecer meio estranha. Ele faz tudo isso pela maneira com que o JavaScript lida com o contexto (`this`). E ele faz isso para que o contexto seja mantido.

```
// [1]   [2]  [3]      [4]      [5][6]
callback.call(context, this[i], i, this)
```

### Estudando o código

Vamos destrinchar:

#### 1. Variável `callback`

Este `callback` é um [predicado](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predicado_(l%C3%B3gica_matem%C3%A1tica)), ou seja,  uma função que retorna verdadeiro ou falso. Por exemplo:

```
const isVegetarian = (food) => !food.containsMeat;
[, , ].filter(isVegetarian);
// resultado: []
```

Veja que no exemplo, `isVegetarian` é o predicado. Uma função que retorna verdadeiro para comidas veganas, ou falso para o contrário. O método `Array.filter` pede um predicado, que é a função que definirá o filtro.

Tanto `Array.some` quanto `Array.every` usam um predicado. Uma função que irá dizer se o item na lista corresponde a uma certa regra.

#### 2. Método `call`

No JavaScript, existem três formas de chamar uma função:

1. `minhaFuncao(x, y, z)`, que é a mais comum
2. `minhaFuncao.call(this, x, y, z)`, que permite modificar o contexto (`this`)
3. `minhaFuncao.call(this, [x, y, z])`, que permite modificar o context e passar argumentos como um Array

No exemplo dado, foi utilizado o `Function.call`.

#### 3. Contexto

Esse argumento é o contexto em que a função será executada. É quem será retornado ao chamar `this`, dentro do predicado.

#### 4. `this[i]`

Dentro do contexto dessa função, o `this` é a instância de `Array`, já que esse método é um método do `Array`. Ao chamar `this[i]`, ele está definindo o primeiro argumento da função de predicado como o item do array. E isso é executado para todos os itens, ou até que se interrompa o loop.

#### 5. `i`

Nessa implementação, o índice do loop é passado como segundo argumento da função de predicado. Veja:

```js
const predicado = function (str, i) {
  console.log(i);
  return str.startsWith("a");
};

["avião", "ana", "alemanha"].every(predicado);
```

#### 6. `this`

E como terceiro argumento da função de predicado, o próprio `Array` é passado. Veja:

```js
const predicado = function (str, i, arr) {
  console.log(arr);
  return str.startsWith("a");
};

["avião", "ana", "alemanha"].every(predicado);
```

Comment: No ultimo exemplo não era para o predicado usar a constante `letra` ?

Answer (score 9):

*Some* significa "algum", então irá retornar imediatamente caso algum item seja encontrado (true):

```
if (callback.call(context, this[i], i, this))
   return true;
```

*Every* significa "cada", "todos de uma lista", ou seja, se encontrar algum que não é o esperado, retorna imediatamente (false):

```
if (!callback.call(context, this[i], i, this))
   return false;
```

Resumindo, `some` para saber se existe algum item na lista que seja o esperado, e `every` para saber se todos os itens são o esperado.